# when to use base or based in sentences

Tags: tense

when to use base or based in sentences
Currently having trouble understanding the differences between using base or based and their meaning

1. I base my decisions on...
2. I based my decision on...

For me (1) means it is applied to the present past and future (basically unchanging situation or repeated situation)

and (2) is just the past.

Can anyone confirm if i am correct and additional example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Use "I **base** my decisions" for describing repeated situations past, present, and (presumably) future. Use "I **based** my decisions" for decisions made only in the past.